# How filter and forward gestures on UIView who covers another UIView with the same size and position?

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

Description is simple. I have 2 subviews (topView and bottomView UIViews) into main view and both cover whole screen. bottomView is bellow topView.

For topView I added double-tap gesture using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and for bottomView I added pinch gesture using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.

**The goal is**: When I made pinch gesture (on the topView) I want to forward that pinch gesture to the bottomView. Double-tap gesture should be executed on the topView. In other words, how to forward only pinch gesture to the bottomView and every other gesture should be executed by topView.

Note: Keep in mind that both UIViews cover whole screen.

I provided code for the start.

I tried to solve this problem overriding UIView's methods hitTest and point, but no luck.

```
import UIKit

let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bottomView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
            return view
        }()

        let topView: UIView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            view.backgroundColor = .orange
            return view
        }()

        let doubleTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTap(sender:)))
        doubleTouch.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        topView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTouch)

        let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch(sender:)))
        bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)

        view.addSubview(bottomView)
        view.addSubview(topView)
    }

    @objc func doubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Double Tap")
    }

    @objc func pinch(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Pinch")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do not you do this add both gesture to both views, and keep the condition inside tap action.

Comment: Because it is a solution specific and complex. Simply, I need to add an extra view on the top that covers whole screen and can get all gestures but only forwards pinch gesture to the view under it.